# Reading Message Embed Data Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot be able to read the description of embeds to see if it includes a certain phrase. I have looked through the documentation, https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=description, and it seems that I would have to do something like this:

`if (message.embeds.description.includes("phrase needed")) ...`

The current error I am getting is `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Embeds in Discord messages are stored in arrays. First, check if the message has any.

```
if (message.embeds.length > 0 && message.embeds[0].description) {
    let desc = message.embeds[0].description;
    console.log(desc);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The link to docs you have provided is for v11. I assume that your bot is using v12, so please refer to v12 docs.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=description

`message.embeds` is plural, meaning multiple and is therefore an array.

You can either use a `forEach` on message.embeds or access the first one using `[0]`